# BAD error CPLEX "opl cannot extract expression: :"

Tags: c++, cplex, opl

im meyla.
i have been running my cplex in bahasa indonesia. but, i get some error "opl cannot extract expression: Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s]*(sum(i in..306)Penugasan_Kerja[i][m]*Waktu_Proses[i]*(-1)+320" in my objective function. but in my objective function, i dont use "*(-1)+320" that 320 is Takttime. at the end, i get error "Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX:CPLEX error 1217: No Solution exist."
can u help me? :(

this is my model in image
[MY MODEL THAT HAVE ERROR IN OBJECTIVE FUNSTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFq8M.png)
[ERROR THAT I HAVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G161i.png)

```
    //Parameter
 int n_Stasiun  =...;
 int n_Operasi  =...;
 int n_PekerjaM=...;
 int n_PekerjaE=...;
 int n_PekerjaT=...;
 int n_Pekerja = n_PekerjaM + n_PekerjaE + n_PekerjaT;
 float TaktTime   =...;
 float TotalTime  =...;
 {string} Skill=...;
 int M=1000000;
 
 range Stasiun = 1..n_Stasiun;
 range Operasi = 1..n_Operasi;
 range Pekerja = 1..n_Pekerja;
 range PekerjaM =1..n_PekerjaM;
 range PekerjaE =n_PekerjaM + 1 .. n_PekerjaM + n_PekerjaE;
 range PekerjaT =n_PekerjaM + n_PekerjaE + 1 .. n_Pekerja;
 
 range PekerjaM_Ringkas= 1..n_PekerjaM - 1;
 range PekerjaE_Ringkas= n_PekerjaM + 1 .. n_PekerjaM + n_PekerjaE - 1;
 range PekerjaT_Ringkas= n_PekerjaM + n_PekerjaE + 1 .. n_Pekerja - 1;
 
 int Kebutuhan_Pekerja [Skill][Operasi] = ...;
 float Waktu_Proses [Operasi] = ... ;
 float ES [Operasi] = ...;
 float LS [Operasi] = ...;
 int arrayOperasi [Skill][Operasi] = ...;
 
 tuple Precedence {
 int Predecessor;
 int Successor;
};
{Precedence} Precedences = ...;  

 tuple Pair {
 int P_Op1;
 int P_Op2;
};
 setof (Pair) A = {<P_Op1,P_Op2> | P_Op1,P_Op2 in Operasi : P_Op1!=P_Op2};

 tuple Samespot {
 int S_Op1; 
 int S_Op2;
 };
 {Samespot} Spot = ...;
 
 //Variables
 dvar float+ Waktu_Mulai [Operasi];
 dvar boolean Penugasan_Kerja [Operasi][Pekerja];
 dvar boolean Penugasan_Kerja_Rangkap [Operasi][Operasi];
 dvar boolean Penyelesaian_Operasi [Operasi][Operasi];
 dvar boolean Penugasan_Stasiun [Operasi][Stasiun];
 dvar boolean Pembagian_Stasiun [Pekerja][Stasiun];
 
 //Model Matematis
 dexpr float Waktu_Menganggur = sum (s in Stasiun)(sum (m in Pekerja)Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s]*(TaktTime-(sum (i in Operasi)Penugasan_Kerja [i][m]*Waktu_Proses[i])));
 
//Fungsi Objektif
minimize Waktu_Menganggur;

//Fungsi Pembatas
subject to {
 forall (i in Operasi)
   cons1 :
   sum (m in Pekerja) Penugasan_Kerja [i][m] == sum (j in Skill) Kebutuhan_Pekerja [j][i];
 forall (i in Operasi : arrayOperasi ["M"][i] == 1)
   cons2 :
   sum (m in PekerjaM) Penugasan_Kerja [i][m] == Kebutuhan_Pekerja ["M"][i];
 forall (i in Operasi : arrayOperasi ["E"][i] == 1)
   cons3 :
   sum (m in PekerjaE) Penugasan_Kerja [i][m] == Kebutuhan_Pekerja ["E"][i];
 forall (i in Operasi : arrayOperasi ["T"][i] == 1)
   cons4 :
   sum (m in PekerjaT) Penugasan_Kerja [i][m] == Kebutuhan_Pekerja ["T"][i];
 
  cons5 :
  Waktu_Mulai [n_Operasi] + Waktu_Proses [n_Operasi] <= TotalTime ;
 
 forall (<Predecessor,Successor> in Precedences)
  cons6 :
  Waktu_Mulai [Successor] - Waktu_Mulai [Predecessor] >= Waktu_Proses [Predecessor];
  
  forall (<P_Op1,P_Op2> in A : P_Op2>P_Op1)
  cons7 :
 Penugasan_Kerja_Rangkap [P_Op1][P_Op2] + Penugasan_Kerja_Rangkap [P_Op2][P_Op1] <= 1;
 
 forall (i in Operasi)
  cons8 :
  Penugasan_Kerja_Rangkap [i][i] == 0;
 
 forall (<P_Op1,P_Op2> in A : P_Op1>P_Op2)
 forall (m in Pekerja)
  cons9 :
  Penugasan_Kerja_Rangkap [P_Op1][P_Op2] + Penugasan_Kerja_Rangkap [P_Op2][P_Op1] >= Penugasan_Kerja [P_Op1][m] + Penugasan_Kerja [P_Op2][m] - 1;
 
 forall (<P_Op1,P_Op2> in A)
  cons10 :
  Waktu_Mulai [P_Op2] - Waktu_Mulai [P_Op1] >= Waktu_Proses [P_Op1] - M * (1 - Penugasan_Kerja_Rangkap [P_Op1][P_Op2]) ;
  
 forall (<S_Op1,S_Op2> in Spot )
  cons11 :
  Waktu_Mulai [S_Op2] + Waktu_Proses [S_Op2] <= Waktu_Mulai [S_Op1] + M * Penyelesaian_Operasi [S_Op1][S_Op2] ;
 
 forall (<S_Op1,S_Op2> in Spot )
  cons12 :
  Waktu_Mulai [S_Op1] + Waktu_Proses [S_Op1] <= Waktu_Mulai [S_Op2] + M * Penyelesaian_Operasi [S_Op2][S_Op1];
  
 forall (<S_Op1,S_Op2> in Spot )
  cons13 :
  Penyelesaian_Operasi [S_Op1][S_Op2] + Penyelesaian_Operasi [S_Op2][S_Op1] == 1;

 forall (i in Operasi)
   cons14 :
   sum (s in Stasiun) Penugasan_Stasiun [i][s] == 1 ;
   
 forall (<Predecessor,Successor> in Precedences  )
   cons15 :
   sum (s in Stasiun) s * (Penugasan_Stasiun [Predecessor][s] - Penugasan_Stasiun [Successor][s]) <= 0 ;
 
 forall (i in Operasi)
  forall (s in Stasiun)
   cons16 :
   sum (m in Pekerja) Penugasan_Kerja [i][m] == sum (j in Skill) Kebutuhan_Pekerja [j][i] * Penugasan_Stasiun [i][s];
   
 forall (i in Operasi)
 forall (m in Pekerja)
   cons17 :
   Penugasan_Kerja [i][m] <= sum (s in Stasiun) Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s];  

 forall (i in Operasi)
 forall (m in Pekerja)
 forall (s in Stasiun)
  cons18 :
  Penugasan_Kerja[i][m] + Penugasan_Stasiun [i][s] <= 1 + Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s];

 forall (m in PekerjaM_Ringkas)
  cons19 :
  sum (s in Stasiun) (Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s] - Pembagian_Stasiun [m+1][s]) >= 0;

 forall (m in PekerjaE_Ringkas)
  cons20 :
  sum (s in Stasiun) (Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s] - Pembagian_Stasiun [m+1][s]) >= 0;

 forall (m in PekerjaT_Ringkas)
  cons21 :
  sum (s in Stasiun) (Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s] - Pembagian_Stasiun [m+1][s]) >= 0;

 forall (i in Operasi)
  cons22 :
  Waktu_Mulai [i] >= ES [i];

 forall (i in Operasi)
  cons23 :
  Waktu_Mulai [i] <= LS [i];

 forall (i in Operasi)
  cons24 :
  Waktu_Mulai [i] >= (-1 + sum(s in Stasiun) s * Penugasan_Stasiun [i][s]) * TaktTime;

 forall (i in Operasi)
  cons25 :
  Waktu_Mulai [i] + Waktu_Proses [i] <= (sum (s in Stasiun) s * Penugasan_Stasiun [i][s]) * TaktTime;

 forall (m in Pekerja)
  cons26 :
  sum (i in Operasi) Penugasan_Kerja [i][m] <= 0 + M * sum (s in Stasiun) Pembagian_Stasiun [m][s];
}




   n_Operasi = 306 ;
 n_Stasiun = 3 ;
 Skill = {M,E,T};
 arrayOperasi = [
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,  //30
 1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,   //60
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,   //90
 1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,   //120
 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,   //150
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,   //180
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   //210
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,   //240
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,   //270
 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,  //300
 0,1,0,0,1,1],
 
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //30
 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //60
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1, //90
 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1, //120
 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //150
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //180
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //210
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //240
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //270
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //300
 0,0,0,0,0,0],
 
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //30
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0, //60
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//90
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//120
 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//150
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,//180
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,//210
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,  //240
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,  //270
 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//300
 1,0,1,1,0,0]
 ];
 
Precedences = 
{<1,2>,<1,3>,<1,4>,<1,5>,<1,6>,<6,7>,<7,8>,<8,9>,<8,10>,<10,11>,<10,12>,
<8,13>,<11,14>,<12,14>,<13,14>,<14,15>,<7,16>,<16,17>,<17,18>,
<17,19>,<16,20>,<18,21>,<19,21>,<20,21>,<21,22>,<22,23>,<15,24>,
<23,25>,<24,25>,<14,26>,<21,26>,<16,27>,<8,28>,<16,28>,<28,29>,
<28,30>,<8,31>,<16,31>,<29,32>,<30,32>,<31,32>,<32,33>,<29,34>,
<30,34>,<29,35>,<30,35>,<29,36>,<14,37>,<37,38>,<21,39>,<39,40>,
<1,41>,<7,42>,<41,42>,<10,43>,<17,43>,<42,43>,<43,44>,
<30,45>,<7,46>,<46,47>,<1,48>,<1,49>,<1,50>,<1,51>,<1,52>,<52,53>,
<35,54>,<36,54>,<45,54>,<47,54>,<48,54>,<49,54>,<50,54>,<51,54>,
<53,54>,<78,54>,<80,54>,<54,55>,<55,56>,<56,57>,<1,58>,<1,59>,
<8,60>,<16,60>,<1,61>,<61,62>,<61,63>,<61,64>,<61,65>,<65,66>,
<1,67>,<1,68>,<68,69>,<68,70>,<70,71>,<1,72>,<1,73>,<73,74>,<1,75>,
<75,76>,<82,76>,<76,77>,<75,78>,<78,79>,<1,80>,<80,81>,<1,82>,
<1,83>,<85,84>,<1,85>,<1,86>,<85,87>,<87,88>,<87,89>,<88,89>,
<89,90>,<69,91>,<84,91>,<87,91>,<69,92>,<87,92>,<1,93>,
<1,94>,<93,95>,<94,95>,<1,96>,<1,97>,<1,98>,<1,99>,<69,100>,
<87,100>,<96,100>,<97,100>,<98,100>,<99,100>,<1,101>,<101,102>,
<1,103>,<1,104>,<1,105>,<1,106>,<106,107>,<69,108>,<87,108>,<102,108>,
<103,108>,<104,108>,<105,108>,<107,108>,<1,109>,<69,110>,<87,110>,
<86,110>,<109,110>,<69,111>,<32,111>,<87,111>,<32,112>,<60,112>,
<32,113>,<69,113>,<84,113>,<1,114>,<114,115>,<114,116>,<1,117>,
<1,118>,<1,119>,<53,120>,<191,120>,<32,121>,<69,121>,<84,121>,<87,121>,
<88,121>,<114,121>,<115,121>,<116,121>,<117,121>,<118,121>,<119,121>,
<120,121>,<128,121>,<121,122>,<121,123>,<90,124>,<80,124>,<108,124>,<110,124>,
<111,124>,<112,124>,<113,124>,<121,124>,<124,125>,<124,126>,<124,127>,
<1,128>,<77,129>,<91,129>,<92,129>,<95,129>,<125,129>,<126,129>,
<127,129>,<128,129>,<129,130>,<130,131>,<131,132>,<132,133>,<133,134>,
<134,135>,<74,136>,<135,136>,<136,137>,<1,138>,<138,139>,<1,140>,
<1,141>,<1,142>,<1,143>,<1,144>,<1,145>,<1,146>,<1,147>,<1,148>,
<1,149>,<1,150>,<1,151>,<1,152>,<152,153>,<1,154>,<1,155>,
<155,156>,<1,157>,<1,158>,<1,159>,<1,160>,<26,161>,<135,161>,<44,162>,
<135,162>,<2,163>,<3,163>,<4,163>,<5,163>,<58,163>,<63,163>,<64,163>,
<66,163>,<135,163>,<140,163>,<141,163>,<142,163>,<143,163>,<144,163>,
<145,163>,<146,163>,<147,163>,<148,163>,<149,163>,<150,163>,<151,163>,
<152,163>,<153,163>,<135,164>,<154,164>,<135,165>,<157,165>,<156,165>,   //196
<72,166>,<135,166>,<159,166>,<160,166>,<57,167>,<135,167>,<57,168>,
<135,168>,<57,169>,<135,169>,<57,170>,<135,170>,<57,171>,<135,171>,
<57,172>,<135,172>,<81,172>,<34,173>,<57,173>,<135,173>,<67,174>,
<135,174>,<186,174>,<135,175>,<179,175>,<180,175>,<135,176>,<185,176>,<7,177>,
<161,178>,<177,178>,<1,179>,<179,180>,<158,181>,<158,182>,<158,183>,
<1,184>,<181,185>,<182,185>,<183,185>,<184,185>,<1,186>,<1,187>,<1,188>,
<155,189>,<8,190>,<16,190>,<1,191>,<191,192>,<135,193>,<135,194>,
<135,195>,<135,196>,<135,197>,<135,198>,<135,199>,<135,200>,<135,201>,
<135,202>,<135,203>,<135,204>,<135,205>,<135,206>,<135,207>,<135,208>,
<135,209>,<135,210>,<135,211>,<135,212>,<135,213>,<135,214>,<135,215>,
<135,216>,<135,217>,<135,218>,<135,219>,<135,220>,<135,221>,<135,222>,
<135,223>,<135,224>,<135,225>,<135,226>,<135,227>,<135,228>,<135,229>,
<135,230>,<135,231>,<135,232>,<135,233>,<135,234>,<135,235>,<135,236>,
<29,237>,<30,237>,<237,238>,<1,239>,<135,240>,<187,240>,<188,240>,
<135,241>,<189,241>,<190,241>,<135,242>,<190,242>,<192,242>,<135,243>,
<71,243>,<135,244>,<238,244>,<25,245>,<38,245>,<40,245>,<135,245>,
<25,246>,<38,246>,<40,246>,<135,246>,<135,247>,<135,248>,<247,248>,
<137,249>,<138,249>,<161,249>,<162,249>,<163,249>,<164,249>,<165,249>,
<166,249>,<167,249>,<168,249>,<169,249>,<170,249>,<171,249>,<172,249>,
<173,249>,<174,249>,<175,249>,<176,249>,<178,249>,<193,249>,<194,249>,
<195,249>,<196,249>,<197,249>,<198,249>,<199,249>,<200,249>,<201,249>,
<202,249>,<203,249>,<204,249>,<205,249>,<206,249>,<207,249>,<208,249>,
<209,249>,<210,249>,<211,249>,<212,249>,<213,249>,<214,249>,<215,249>,
<216,249>,<217,249>,<218,249>,<219,249>,<220,249>,<221,249>,<222,249>,
<223,249>,<224,249>,<225,249>,<226,249>,<227,249>,<228,249>,<229,249>,
<230,249>,<231,249>,<232,249>,<233,249>,<234,249>,<235,249>,<236,249>,
<239,249>,<240,249>,<241,249>,<242,249>,<243,249>,<244,249>,<245,249>,
<246,249>,<247,249>,<248,249>,<249,250>,<250,251>,<251,252>,<251,253>,
<251,254>,<251,255>,<121,256>,<256,257>,<257,258>,<191,259>,<53,260>,<191,260>,
<9,261>,<27,261>,<33,261>,<59,261>,<121,261>,<122,261>,<123,261>,<258,261>,
<259,261>,<260,261>,<121,262>,<8,263>,<16,263>,<263,264>,<12,265>,
<18,265>,<58,265>,<82,265>,<83,265>,<140,265>,<141,265>,<142,265>,
<143,265>,<144,265>,<145,265>,<146,265>,<147,265>,<148,265>,<149,265>,
<150,265>,<152,265>,<264,265>,<7,266>,<8,267>,<16,267>,<53,268>,
<191,268>,<53,269>,<191,269>,<248,270>,<266,270>,<267,270>,<268,270>,
<269,270>,<1,271>,<1,272>,<135,273>,<271,273>,<272,273>,<135,274>,<135,275>,
<135,276>,<126,277>,<126,278>,<278,279>,<279,280>,<1,281>,<126,282>,<281,282>,
<1,283>,<126,284>,<283,284>,<277,285>,<277,286>,<277,287>,<277,288>,<288,289>,
<288,290>,<1,291>,<291,292>,<292,293>,<1,294>,<1,295>,<1,296>,<1,297>,<1,298>,
<1,299>,<1,300>,<62,301>,<79,301>,<124,301>,<139,301>,<261,301>,<262,301>,
<265,301>,<270,301>,<271,301>,<272,301>,<273,301>,<274,301>,<275,301>,<276,301>,
<277,301>,<279,301>,<280,301>,<281,301>,<282,301>,<284,301>,<285,301>,<286,301>,
<287,301>,<288,301>,<289,301>,<290,301>,<293,301>,<294,301>,<295,301>,<296,301>,
<297,301>,<298,301>,<301,302>,<302,303>,<252,305>,<253,305>,<254,305>,<255,305>,
<270,305>,<273,305>,<274,305>,<275,305>,<276,305>,<304,305>,<305,306>};

Spot = {<1,306>};
 
TaktTime = 320;
TotalTime = 960;
 
Waktu_Proses = [2.75,2.31,3.39,3.32,8.51,6.41,17.22,5.99,6.59,7.92,  //10
3.55,1.78,10.79,9.03,7.48,5.99,7.92,1.78,4.03,9.07,9.03,7.48,0.65,  //23
0.65,4.76,0.81,6.31,5.06,5.24,5.32,7.31,17.27,11.26,3.61,12.1,5.25,  //36
1.15,7.73,1.05,7.73,5.31,8.51,2.93,10.88,4.74,1.59,10.13,4.61,4.61,  //49
7.84,3.14,5.9,6.92,15,10.39,8.69,3.77,9.37,7.74,4.52,8.74,2.59,0.79, //63
0.84,4.18,3.51,10.52,8.16,22.93,10.35,4.05,18.25,28.41,3.08,7.35,11.27, //76
79.14,4.01,2.91,6.07,0.79,8.82,3.72,16.16,1.41,4.05,62.47,4.22,33.15, //89
20.03,95.93,32.86,40.04,3.99,12.62,4.35,19.34,3.23,22.47,79.29,19.17, //101
2,2.49,2.19,17.56,8.33,1.37,4.89,2.38,37.34,10.93,11.54,13.73,9.3,  //114
1.32,3.55,9.46,6.55,2.77,3.48,35.19,7.39,12.88,10.4,6.83,6.75,10.16,  //127
0.42,8,8,8,8,8,8,3.27,9.07,5.06,3.04,3.04,2.6,1.95,5.3,3.08,3.69,5.91, //145
6.5,2.89,1.87,8,4.92,2.59,4.53,5.75,8.63,7.52,10.15,2.02,6.04,6.11,   //159
10.84,9.07,2.63,10.6,9.81,3.5,3.91,30.85,25.1,12.55,10.39,9.81,11,    //172
10.55,4.31,10.6,4.55,7.43,7.78,3.14,6.78,9.06,3.35,30.96,4.29,16.11,  //185
8.38,2.21,4.29,2.86,3,1.92,1.36,5.17,9.6,9.85,15.76,18.83,7,7,6.33,   //200
10.13,11.04,10.12,3.88,2.89,10.26,3.36,4.31,5.33,5.25,13.03,6.33,7,   //213
12.6,17.42,6.83,10.6,11.06,3.77,4,8.55,11.66,6.79,10.88,10.47,10.47,   //226
6.83,6.83,6.83,11.76,4.32,18.83,5.25,10.6,8.86,2.2,7.13,3.38,0.41,     // 239
4.47,5.33,3.97,5.27,4.55,8.41,8.72,6.11,10.93,7.41,6.83,8.17,12.02,   //252
5.75,8.37,5.33,6.71,6.49,7.12,17.1,25.06,2.59,2.51,12.35,7.83,0.87,   //265
5.38,8.08,7,24.87,8.72,6.62,7.25,10.6,4.4,8.41,6.23,3.34,4.83,28.51,  //279
0.79,2.14,2.14,2.59,2.59,47.66,5.43,1.22,1.54,0.19,2.28,3.78,2.56,    //292
1.18,6.44,1.96,3.32,6.02,3.68,1.76,0.38,14.11,3.03,10.07,3.25,3.2,6.9];
 
Kebutuhan_Pekerja = [
[3,2,2,2,4,7,6,4,4,3,2,2,6,4,5,5,3,2,3,6,4,5,2,2,2,2,4,2,4,4,4,2,6  //33
4,4,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,0,2,4,7,4,4,6,2,2,4,2,6,4,0,4,8,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,  //66
4,4,0,4,2,6,4,7,2,2,0,4,2,2,2,6,6,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,5,5,4,2,0,4,4,2,6,  //99
0,4,0,0,4,6,6,2,0,4,0,0,0,0,6,2,4,2,2,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //132
0,0,0,0,0,4,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,5,2,2,2,2,2,7,4,6,2,2,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,  //165
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,4,2,3,4,6,8,2,2,4,6,4,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //198
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //231
0,0,0,0,0,6,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,4,4,6,6,2,2,4,6,  //264
2,2,7,4,6,0,5,4,0,0,0,0,2,2,4,2,4,4,2,2,6,5,2,4,2,5,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,  //297
2,4,2,0,6,0,0,2,1],

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,  //33
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   //66
0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,   //99
2,0,2,6,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,   //132
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //165
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //198
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //231
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //264
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //297
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //30
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0, //60
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //90
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //120
 0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //150
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,0,0, //180
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, //210
 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,  //240
 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,  //270
 0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //300
 2,0,2,2,0,0]
 ];

n_PekerjaM = 30 ;
n_PekerjaE = 6 ;
n_PekerjaT = 11 ;
 
ES = [0,0,0,0,0,0,8,24,32,32,56,56,32,56,64,24,32,56,56,32,56,64, //22
72,72,72,64,32,32,32,32,32,56,72,56,56,56,64,64,64,64,0,24,56,56, //44
56,24,24,0,0,0,0,0,8,64,80,112,120,0,0,32,0,8,8,8,8,8,0,0,8,8,16, //71
0,0,24,0,8,16,8,8,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,80,136,80,80,0,0,56,0,0,0,0, //99
80,0,16,0,0,0,0,8,80,0,80,80,72,72,0,8,8,0,0,0,8,80,136,136,192,  //124
200,200,200,0,224,232,240,248,256,264,272,280,288,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  //144
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,8,0,0,0,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,  //168
280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,24,288,0,0,8,8,8,0,32,0,0,0,8,32, //190
0,0,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,
280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,
280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,56,64,0,280, //240
280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,328,336,336,344,344,344,344,360, //256
368,368,8,8,392,392,32,56,64,32,32,8,8,296,0,0,280,280,280,280,  //276
224,224,224,256,0,224,0,224,224,224,224,224,224,224,0,0,8,0,0,0, //296
0,0,0,0,336,352,352,360,392,392];

LS = [0,312,312,312,304,64,72,88,336,280,288,296,280,296,304,88, //16
280,296,288,288,296,304,312,312,312,304,336,112,120,120,112,120, //32
312,312,224,232,304,312,304,312,296,296,304,304,232,232,232,232,232, //49
232,240,120,128,240,256,280,288,304,336,176,296,344,312,312,304, //65
312,312,32,56,304,312,304,280,304,80,88,112,232,344,80,312,336,336, //83
64,0,136,0,120,120,168,80,176,144,192,200,72,56,72,56,80,144,184, //102
184,184,168,176,184,184,136,136,176,176,176,128,136,136,128,136, //118
136,136,136,336,312,192,200,200,200,136,224,232,240,248,256,280, //134
288,312,336,336,344,312,312,312,312,312,312,304,312,312,304,312, //150
312,304,312,304,304,312,336,248,312,312,304,336,312,312,336,336, //166
296,296,312,312,312,312,312,336,312,336,312,336,304,304,296,304, //182
256,296,304,312,336,312,336,336,136,336,336,312,312,312,304,344, //198
344,336,312,312,312,336,336,312,336,336,336,336,312,336,344,312, //214
304,336,312,312,336,336,336,312,336,312,312,312,336,336,336,312, //230
336,304,336,312,312,336,312,336,344,336,336,336,336,336,336,312, //246
304,312,344,352,352,360,368,368,368,304,312,336,312,304,344,344, //262
304,336,344,312,312,312,296,336,312,312,336,344,336,336,280,296, //278
296,344,344,344,336,344,280,336,344,344,344,344,336,344,344,336, //294
344,344,336,344,344,344,344,360,360,368,392,392];
```

Comment: Could you please post the full .mod file here? At least up to the `subject to` statement. Your picture does not show how `Waktu_Proses` is defined. I suspect that this is a decision variable as well and that you end up with a product of three decision variables, which is not supported. But I cannot be sure before I see the definition of this item.

Comment: i already edit my full .mod, daniel. plis, i need u help @DanielJunglas

Comment: It is not obvious what could be wrong with your objective function. Would it be possible to provide the data for you rmodel so that we can run this here and see what may be wrong?

Comment: sure @DanielJunglas. i already add my data in this question. thanks you

Comment: That is weird. Your code runs without a problem here. Your model is infeasible but I don't get any issue with "cannot extract expression". What version of CPLEX do you use?

Comment: i use CPLEX Optimization 12.9.0 @DanielJunglas :(

Comment: when u try to running, what u get from thats data and model? @DanielJunglas

Comment: I have the same results with 12.9 and 12.10: the model is created just fine, no "cannot extract" error. But then the model is infeasible. Could you try to clear all errors in the "Problems" tab in the IDE and then re-run your model? Do you still get the "cannot extract" error? Or only the "no solution available"?

Comment: how to clear all error if in my cplex still have an error that must be completed first @DanielJunglas ?

Comment: In the IDE in the error tab if you right click you will see "delete messages"

Comment: i already run. but its still sama. error found :( i need help @AlexFleischer

Comment: Hi, I tried and I get infeasible.too.I do not see any error.If instead of the IDE I use oplrun then I get <<< no solution.